# Looking for idiom that expresses "one for another, payoff for a grudge"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I need an idiom if possible or a good expression to say this :

this one *(your payoff)* is for the another one *(a grudge that he know, something bad that he did to you)*

Comment: Some additional context might help in answering this question. Literally, it sounds like you're looking for 'quid pro quo' (or more colloquially 'tit for tat'), but from the context you do provide, it seems you might be looking for something more like 'recompense'. Could you use a more complete sentence that demonstrates the potential usage?

Comment: thanks tit for tat will do. i tried to make it clear as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Tit for Tat" is good, or "this is [your] payback!"

Answer (score 1):

**Revenge is a dish best savoured cold** (or savored in US).

[image]

Comment: That’s ***served** cold*.

Comment: @tchrist I prefer my gazpacho served chilled.

Comment: thanks but this is not what i wanted